# Sales Team Sublist

Tags: netsuite, sublist

We have team selling enabled on our NetSuite, so the bottom of our customer form contains the Sales Team sublist, like below.

My question is a simple one - can I access the fields in that sublist to disable them for certain users, change the labels, etc? If so, how? As far as I can see, it's all OOB and I can't find a way to edit any of it.[image]

Comment: Looks like you'll need a script. Are you ok with that? Let me know and I can post an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm quite happy to use a script if that's the only way to do it...any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Gotcha covered. A bit busy ATM, but I'll write back around 8 hours from now with a solution. We'll probably need to discuss in the comments some. But we'll figure it out!

Comment: Thanks so much. My primary need at the moment is to disable the CHOOSE TEAM drop down and the buttons - the Add and Cancel ones at the bottom. I can't figure out how to get to them at all - to enable/disable or to change their text. We need to be able to show this list to all users, but prevent them from making any edits to it.

Comment: Noted. I think this is possible but it's definitely going to be a few iterations before we get it right. I'll comment back when I'm on later (about 8 hours from now), so you know I'm active. Once I post an answer, we can move our comments to the answer and edit back and forth. Is that ok with you?

Comment: That sounds great - thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Hey! Had some issues to handle, just getting to this now. I'll need the weekend to work through it, though I do promise I'll write back. Talk soon.